# Help me uninstall Photoshop!

Tags: software-installation, wine, uninstall, adobe, photoshop

I was installing photoshop and found out my PC wont be able to run the newer versions. So I decided to uninstall it and install a previous version. But it won't uninstall. I tried using the code "sudo apt remove PhotoshopCC". I have attached a SS of it. It won't even open up. I tried deleting all its files. Please Help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRaZT.png)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Your question unfortunately is unclear.  Can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1432020/edit) your question and add more details like the version of Ubuntu you are running, and also any information you have about how you installed Photoshop on your system?  Thank you!

Comment: How did you install photoshop?

Comment: I guess, you should look for a solution on playforlinux: https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-3066-Adobe_Photoshop_CC_2015.html